# Get options for select in forms from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm programming the server side using PHP and got stuck.

I want to create a set of input fields using select tags for a form.
The options for the select should be fetched from my database and the option selected in the first input will decide the options in the second input.

For example, the two fields are country and state. First, the user selects their country name which will decide the list of states that appear in the state input field. I want the list to change dynamically when user changes the country.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in **PHP** submitting a select each time.

For example:

```
 <form action="selectState.php" method="post">
  <select name="country">
   <option value="countryName">countryName</option>
   ...
  </select>
 </form>
```

then you get the value of *$_POST['country']* in selectState.php and print the select the way you want it:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
  <select name="state">
   <?php
     // select use $_POST['country'] to customize the select option's
   ?>
  </select>
 </form>
```

---

A more user friendly solution (that does not require a new page or refresh) is use **AJAX**.

So you can use this kind of form:

```
<form action="selectState.php" method="post">
  <select name="country" onchange="ajaxFunction(this.value)">
   <option value="countryName">countryName</option>
   ...
  </select>
  <select name="state" id="stateList">
   <!-- here we'll put the states we want -->
  </select>
 </form>
```

With this everytime the user change the select value ajaxFunction() is called and pass to the function the current value selected.

Here is the ajaxFunction (NOTE: this example use jQuery but you can do it in vanilla javascript):

```
function ajaxFunction(val){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post', // choose the method
    url: 'page.php', // choose the 'action' page
    data: {
      country:val // send the data
    },
    success: function (response) {
      // this tell the browser what to do with the response of 'page.php'
      // in this case we are telling to put everything we get to the HTML element with stateList id 
      document.getElementById("stateList").innerHTML=response;
    }
  });
}
```

The last thing you need its 'page.php' that simply query the DB (NOTE: this is pseudo code):

```
<?php

 // Query the DB for the states with country = $_POST['country']
 while(results){
  echo '<option value="results[$i]">results[$i]</option>';
 }

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a php framework such as Laravel (recommended) or Codeigniter (not sure if this is still in development).

If so you can construct a 2d php array of countries each with an sub array of its states.

This can be put directly into the rendering page (view).
Using something like

```
 var countries_list =<?php echo json_encode($countries_array); ?>;
```

will directly inject this into a javascript array which you can use to populate the state select when the country select changes.

Or use ajax but that will be slower and hit the server more.